# dreamfactory: how to filter on related objects

Tags: api

For my app I have Cinemas and Addresses. Cinemas are related to Addresses through a foreign keys. When displaying a list of Cinemas I want to filter them by Addresses.Districts.name of the Cinema.

how can i make such a query in Dreamfactory API?

Comment: [Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), also as an audio engineer...what has this got to do with signal processing??

Comment: good stuff changing from signal processing, i would say most would say the best way is to start and come back when you run into a wall with code. then show it to us with the problem explained.

Comment: my friend there's no code for this problem.
its either dreamfactory api allow such a filter or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a little more of an idea on how to approach your query, though your data model may be slightly more complex than this...

> Here is a simple example:
>
> Let's assume Cinemas is the parent table and Addresses is the child
>   table.
>
> Each Cinema can have any number of related Addresses.
>
> The Addresses table has a column named "CinemaId".
>
> To get all Cinemas that have an Address where state=CA you could make
>   the following query.
>
> GET /rest/db/Addresses?related=Cinemas_by_CinemaId&filter=state='CA'
>
> It's a good idea to escape filter string to state%3D'CA'.
>
> In the results each Addresses record that matched the query will
>   contain the parent Cinemas record as an object named
>   Cinemas_by_CinemaId.

Let us know if you need a little more insight.

Comment: Thank you dream3r, your answer solved part of my problem. The other part is: how can i fetch cinema's related objects. (i.e cinemases_by_addressId.related = cinemaslocalizations_by_cinemaId)

Comment: go ahead and shoot an email to me support@dreamfactory.com

Comment: Can you give a example URL?